# Is there a way to make Android in general play sound a little louder on the right side?

Tags: audio, music, google-play-music

For some reason my earphones have a lower volume on the right side and it throws me off, is there a non-root way to make the phone's audio (at least via earphones) play a little bit louder on the right side? I'm using an Xperia Z Ultra on the latest available Android version for it (Lollipop).

Answer (score 1):

**Settings** -> **Accessibility** > **Hearing**,

There you can control the left/right sound balance.

Comment: There's nothing for audio or hearing in the Accessibility menu in Settings